hlsl - how do i avoid using switch statement?
i recently started working with shaders, and i’d like to avoid using a switch statement.
it keeps getting longer and i’m wondering if there are alternative approaches or patterns i can use.
below is my code.
inline float GetShapeDistance(const float3 pos, const int type, const float3 size)
{
    switch (type)
    {
    case SPHERE:
        return Sphere(pos, size.x);
    case ELLIPSOID:
        return Ellipsoid(pos, size);
    case BOX:
        return Box(pos, size);
    case OCTAHEDRON:
        return Octahedron(pos, size.x);
    case CAPSULE:
        return Capsule(pos, size.xy);
    // ...
    default:
        return Sphere(pos, size.x);
    }
}


I am not an expert at hlsl. However, according to my research it is similar top c and you can use pointers.
One effective way to eliminate a long switch statement is to use an array of function pointers. This allows you to map each shape type to a corresponding distance function. Here's how you can implement this:
typedef float (*DistanceFunction)(float3, float3);

float Sphere(float3 pos, float size);
float Ellipsoid(float3 pos, float3 size);
float Box(float3 pos, float3 size);
float Octahedron(float3 pos, float size);
float Capsule(float3 pos, float2 size);

// Define an array of function pointers
DistanceFunction distanceFunctions[] = {
    Sphere,         // 0: SPHERE
    Ellipsoid,     // 1: ELLIPSOID
    Box,           // 2: BOX
    Octahedron,    // 3: OCTAHEDRON
    Capsule        // 4: CAPSULE
};

inline float GetShapeDistance(const float3 pos, const int type, const float3 size)
{
    if (type < 0 || type >= sizeof(distanceFunctions) / sizeof(distanceFunctions[0]))
    {
        return Sphere(pos, size.x); // Default case
    }
    return distanceFunctions[type](pos, size);
}


thanks for your response, but the code gives me errors. i don't think it supports function pointers...
